# Add custom field to all existing projects in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

Is there any way how to add new custom field to all youtrack projects?

Thank you
Ales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's a [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-17681) in the JetBrains public tracker. A workaround is also offered in the comments.

Comment: WoW, thank you. That future request is 9 yo. So that does not look like it will be ever solved. That is shame. Anyway thank you.